# Functions not recognized as being part of namespace

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am writing a short unit-test-like program as part of a larger project. I have written a few simple functions in a "Utilities.hpp" file which I am writing tests for.  Here is the code... some function definitions have been excluded for lengths' sake.

```
//Main.cpp
#ifdef RUN_TESTS

#include "Logger.hpp"
#include "UnitTester.hpp"


#define TEST_ALL

int main(int, char*[])
{
    logger::init();
    logger::setSeverityLevel(INFO);
    auto slg = logger::getSLogger();

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, INFO) << "Starting Unit Tests...";

    testing::UnitTester testObject;
    testObject.runTests();
}

#endif
```

Utilities.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>


namespace util
{
    void swapChars(char& a, char& b);   //flips two chars

    std::string reverseString(const std::string& str);  //stack based implementation of string inversion

    std::vector<std::string> splitStrAtSubstr(const std::string& str, const std::string& split);    //splits string into parts seperated by "split"
}
```

Utilities.cpp

```
#include "Utilities.hpp"



void util::swapChars(char& a, char& b)
{

...

}

std::string util::reverseString(const std::string& str)
{
...
}


std::vector<std::string> util::splitStrAtSubstr(const std::string& str, const std::string& split)
{
...
}
```

Lastly the UnitTester class...
UnitTester.hpp

```
#pragma once
#define RUN_TESTS
#define RUN_ALL
#ifdef RUN_TESTS

#include "Logger.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace testing
{

    class UnitTester
    {
    public:
        UnitTester();
        ~UnitTester();
        void runTests();

    private:
        src::severity_logger<severity_level> testLogger;

        void utilities();
        void logging();
        void resourceGroup();
        void resourceManager();
        void INIParser();
    };

}
#endif
```

UnitTester.cpp

```
#include "UnitTester.hpp"
#ifdef RUN_TESTS


void testing::UnitTester::runTests()
{
#ifdef RUN_ALL
    utilities();
    logging();
    resourceGroup();
    resourceManager();
    INIParser();
#elif
    #ifdef TEST_UTILITIES
        utilities();
    #endif
    #ifdef TEST_LOGGING
            logging();
    #endif
    #ifdef TEST_RESOURCE_GROUP
            resourceGroup();
    #endif
    #ifdef TEST_RESOURCE_MANAGER
            resourceMananager();
    #endif
    #ifdef TEST_INI_PARSER
            INIParser();
    #endif
#endif
}

//PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

void testing::UnitTester::utilities()
{
#include "Utilities.hpp"

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, INFO) << "Now testing: void util::swapChars(char& a, char& b);";
    char a = 'a', b = 'b';
    util::swapChars(a, b);
    if (a != 'b' || b != 'a') { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::swapChars failed."; }

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, INFO) << "Now testing: std::string util::reverseString(const std::string& str);";
    if (util::reverseString("myString") != "gnirtSym") { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::reverseString failed.  IN: \"myString\""; }
    if (util::reverseString("MYSTRING ") != " GNIRTSYM") { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::reverseString failed.  IN: \"MYSTRING \""; }
    if (util::reverseString("aaaaaa") != "aaaaaa") { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::reverseString failed.  IN: \"aaaaaa\""; }
    if (util::reverseString("This Is An Extended TEST") != "TSET dednetxE nA sI sihT") { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::reverseString failed.  IN: \"This Is An Extended Test\""; }
    if (util::reverseString("\"\\\"Escape") != "epacsE\"\\\"") { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::reverseString failed.  IN: \"\"\\\"Escape\""; }

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, INFO) << "Now testing: std::vector<std::string> splitStrAtSubstr(const std::string& str, const std::string& split)";
    std::vector<std::string> expected("One", "Two", "Three");
    std::vector<std::string> expected2("One", "Three");
    if (util::splitStrAtSubstr("One.Two.Three", ".") != expected) { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::splitStrAtSubstr failed. IN: \"One.Two.Three\", \".\""; }
    if (util::splitStrAtSubstr("One\"Two\"Three", "\"") != expected) { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::splitStrAtSubstr failed. IN: \"One\"Two\"Three\", \"\"\""; }
    if (util::splitStrAtSubstr("OneTwoThree", ".") != expected) { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::splitStrAtSubstr failed. IN: \"One.Two.Three\", \".\""; }
    if (util::splitStrAtSubstr("OneTwoThree", "Two") != expected) { BOOST_LOG_SEV(testLogger, ERROR) << "Input to util::splitStrAtSubstr failed. IN: \"OneTwoThree\", \"Two\""; }

}

void testing::UnitTester::logging()
{
#include "Logger.hpp"
}

void testing::UnitTester::resourceGroup()
{
#include "ResourceManager\ResourceGroup.hpp"
}

void testing::UnitTester::resourceManager()
{
#include "ResourceManager\ResourceGroup.hpp"
}

void testing::UnitTester::INIParser()
{
#include "INIParser.hpp"
}
#endif
```

Here is what I think to be a representative sample of the different errors I am getting.  I'll put the ones I think most suspect at the top.  As they often do, many of the errors are just caused due to other ones...

On function declarations in Utilities.hpp:

Error   14  error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'std'
Error   13  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
Error   15  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
Error   10  error C2039: 'string' : is not a member of 'std'

On BOOST_LOG_SEV calls in UnitTester.hpp:

Error   69  error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'testing::UnitTester::testLogger'
Error   49  error C2228: left of '.stream' must have class/struct/union 
Error   63  error C2228: left of '.open_record' must have class/struct/union

On function calls in UnitTester.cpp:

Error   51  error C2039: 'splitStrAtSubstr' : is not a member of 'util'

Error   31  error C2664: 'int util::reverseString(const int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'const int'
^^happens because compiler cannot find std::string as type and defaults to int

These are the most important of the errors it seems.  To me the problem is almost certainly occuring in Utilities.hpp where the compiler seems to not recognize std::string and std::vector and comes up with some wierd interpretation of the function declarations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get an error saying `vector` is not defined in a header file where you first do `#include <vector>`?  Are you sure?  It looks like there is something you may not be showing us somehow.  For one thing, you never `#include <Utilities.h>` anywhere other than in `Utilities.cpp` which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include files from inside function bodies, which i don't think it is meant to be used like.

`#include` is a precompiler directive. The precompiler is run even before the actual compiler starts. This enables it to modify code. Like how #define can substitute certain words, #include can include entire files.

```
void testing::UnitTester::logging()
{
#include "Logger.hpp"
}
```

Imagine what the compiler would actually receive, like if you replaced `#include "Logger.hpp"` with the contents of Logger.hpp.

Please don't use `#include` inside a function body.

Comment: Indeed, the C++ standard specifically says, "A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition".  While the standard is talking specifically about the headers that the standard defines, one would be wise to do the same for any header except for some very rarely encountered ones that are specifically designed to be used inside a function definition.

Comment: That fixed everything.  I guess I was trying to be too fancy.